# In the Repository Pattern, does the Repository have to be a Collection Like interface?

Tags: c#, repository-pattern

I'm developing a Windows application, and trying to separate the layers by applying the Repository Pattern. Collections used in the business layer can be saved and loaded by converting them to string data. For example, the string data format is as follows.

**"0, e0 data, 1, e1 data, 2, e2 data"**

Two values separated by commas represent one element in the Collection, and the first value indicates the index. In the business layer, you can change the order of elements in the collection, and of course the changed order is stored as string data.

**"0, e2 data, 1, e1 data, 2, e0 data"**

But, in this situation, the common Repository interface methods seems to be a problem. For example, the Add() method of the Repository add a single element, but the string data being stored requires the entire data in the collection. Problems can arise if the single element order already is changed.

In the business layer, the elements of that collection are not used only partially. Always use all elements. In this case, the Collection Like interface may not be suitable. What do you think? If I use an interface other than Collection Like, can I use the interface that passes the Collection itself?

```
public interface IExampleRepository<T>
{
   IEnumerable<T> Get();
   void Add(IEnumerable<T> collection);
   void Remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must using an entity model. It doesn't matter how data are stored.
I think the entity you'r trying to build must be

```
public class MyData
{
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
// ...
new MyData // first data
{
    Order = 0,
    Data = "e0 data",
}
```

The repositoty pattern will implement how data will be stored, and you will work with your entity without knowing how they are stored.

Comment: In more detail, there are several types of Collection, and the Root type includes all types of collections as property. And there are many instances of the Root type and they are managed as an array. The end goal is to save and load the string data of Root instance array, and it should be possible to unit test each internal collection of specific Root instance.

Comment: "includes all types of collections" ?

Comment: There are several modules in the application, and there are also corresponding collections specific to the module. Elements stored in Collection contain various information used for a specific module. The structure of element is a bit complicated, but the logic to convert to string data for collection(containing multiple elements) has already been implemented.

Comment: I think the first thing you need to do is isolate the string convertion of your objects in the repository pattern. if i understand, your strings are the stored representation of your object state. With a repository pattern you need to work with defined entities (books, users, cars, ...). The collections inside the entities only represents the actual association between them.

Comment: Then, only the Root type is treated as a Repository Entity,
and if i want to apply unit test only to some of the member collections of the root type instance, is it correct to find another way?

Comment: if there's already unit test you will need to modify them to match your new structure